# Reading Outer Nested Forms in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way to do this:

```
(let ((x 5)(y 7))
    (get-outer-form) ;; 'get-outer-form would capture the entire LET expression
    (* x y))

35                   ;; value returned from LET

*current-form-value* ;; variable to hold the form

(let ((x 5))(y 7))(* x y)) ;; value of evaluating *current-form-value*
```

If it can be done, pseudo-code will suffice. I'll naively assume that this would have to be done with `read`, however, if there is too much overhead generated from doing this, I will have to find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for some way to set `*current-form-value*` with the code of the outermost `let` as data or as a function? What exactly are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Sorry, just got back from running. Data, and I'd rather not say at this time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No its not possible by default. Doing so would need some advanced code and is not likely to work easily:

- custom evaluator
- code walker which injects the necessary code

Comment: Custom evaluator I get, implementing it... Could you explain the code walker piece, please?

Answer (score 3):

I've been fiddling a little around and came up with this. It's not exactly what you want but it's close. It it were possible to rename `let` and make your own it would be exactly what you want.

```
(defmacro letc (p &body b)
  (when (equal (car b) '(get-outer-form))
      (setq b `((setf *current-form-value* '(let ,p ,@(cdr b))),@(cdr b))))
  `(let ,p ,@b))

(letc ((x 5)(y 7))
    (get-outer-form) ;; 'get-outer-form would capture the entire LET expression
    (* x y))
;; ==> 35

*current-form-value*
;; ==> (let ((x 5) (y 7)) (* x y))
```

Or simpler. Using `letc` implies you want it captured.

```
(defmacro letc (p &body b)
  `(let ,p (setf *current-form-value* '(letc ,p ,@b)),@b)))

(letc ((x 5)(y 7))
    (* x y))
;; ==> 35

*current-form-value*
;; ==> (letc ((x 5) (y 7)) (* x y))
```

Both of them have problems with nesting:

```
 (letc ((x 5)(y 7))
   (letc ((a (+ x y))) 
     (* 2 a)))
 ;; ==> 24

*current-form-value*
;; ==> (let ((a (+ x y))) (* 2 a))
```

Comment: I was thinking of a macro solution, this looks pretty much like what I want, however I would need to make it more the general case where I'd have to capture whatever function(let, lambda, +,...) forms it comes across. I'll work on it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think Rainer is basically correct, but I couldn't help trying for a subset of your goal with either *macroexpand-hook* or a reader approach. I don't bother removing (get-outer-form) from the current form in either case, but that should be straightforward list manipulation.

First a reader approach. Wrap the open parenthesis reader with a function that searches for (get-outer-form) within the result of calling the default open parenthesis reader.

```
;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defparameter *standard-readtable* (copy-readtable ()))
*STANDARD-READTABLE*

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defvar *current-form-value* ())
*CURRENT-FORM-VALUE*

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defun get-outer-form ()
  ())
GET-OUTER-FORM

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defun get-outer-form-paren-reader (stream char &optional count)
  (declare (ignore count))
  (let* ((seen ())
         (paren-reader
          (get-macro-character #\( *standard-readtable*))
         (form (funcall paren-reader stream char)))
    (subst-if ()
              (lambda (x)
                ;; never substitute, search only.
                (prog1 ()
                  (when (equalp x '(get-outer-form))
                    (setq seen t))))
              form)
    (when seen
      (setq *current-form-value* form))
    form))
GET-OUTER-FORM-PAREN-READER

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(set-macro-character #\( #'get-outer-form-paren-reader)
T
```

Second, a *macroexpand-hook* approach. Look for (get-outer-form) in forms before they are macroexpanded.

```
;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defun get-outer-form ()
  (error "get-outer-form only works from within a macro"))
GET-OUTER-FORM

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defvar *current-form-value* ())
*CURRENT-FORM-VALUE*

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(defun mhook (expander form env)
  (let* ((seen ())
         (fixed (subst-if ()
                          (lambda (x)
                            (when (equalp x '(get-outer-form))
                              (setq seen t)))
                          form)))
    (when seen (setq *current-form-value* form))
    (funcall expander fixed env)))
MHOOK

;(in-package |cl-user|)
(setq *macroexpand-hook* #'mhook)
#<Compiled-function MHOOK #x30200FC5BB1F>
```

Comment: I saw this a few hours ago, had to go the _HyperSpec_ to figure out just what the code was doing... Gotta say, I'm very impressed. I'll probably go with the reader example since I plan to extend the functionality. **Both** code segments are fit for use! Thanks.

Comment: Just figured out what you were doing the _subst-if_ and _prog1_, nice.